# The following ODE global existence theorem reference?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

There is an ODE existence theorem of the form:

> Let $f:[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Caratheodory function.
>
> Suppose that there is a constant $c$ such that if $y$ is a solution, then $|y(t)| \leq c$ on any subinterval of $[a,b]$.
>
> Furthermore, if $|v| \leq C$, there is a $h_C \in L^1$ such that $|f(t,v)| \leq h_C(t)$. Then the ODE $y'(t) = f(t,y(t))$ with $y(0)=y_0$ has a global solution on $[a,b]$ (solution here means the equation holds pointwise a.e.).

Does anyone know of a reference for this statment (apart from Zeidler)? I am particularly needing the condition about $h_C$ with the integrability bound only on a ball of radius $C$.

Comment: This statement is incorrect. A counterexample is $f(t,x) = x^2, h_C(t) = C^2$. For $y_0 = 1$ the solution is $y(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: You may be looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carathéodory%27s_existence_theorem

Comment: @HansEngler Why is it incorrect? You just gave a solution. the ODE is understood as holding pointwise a.e.

Comment: @ChrisAl - the solution does not exist globally, only on $[0,1)$.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks, I think the new edit should rule out such a case provided we can take the subinterval to be $[a,b]$ (I forgot to write the new assumption).

Comment: Reposted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209555/the-following-ode-global-existence-theorem-reference